# Having an outline for MouseOver for a WPF ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I am using Windows 7 and the current item selection (by default) is to paint the background with cornflower blue. Is it possible to get rid of this and replace it with a 1px outline/border over the listview item that the mouse is over?

I basically want to draw a 1px outline/border over any listview item with 1 pixel spacing between the listview item and the outline/border.

I am using a WrapPanel with an Image in it for each item.

Answer (score 4):

Use ItemContainerStyle to override the default background behaviour, and in your style, use a trigger on IsMouseOver to show your outline (for example by having a Setter for BorderThickness).

**EDIT:** Rough example (not tested):

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
          <Border Background="White" BorderThickness="5" Name="Bd">
            <Border.Style>
              <Style TargetType="Border">
                 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
              </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <ContentPresenter />
          </Border>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
              <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="HotPink" />
            </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to WPF. Can you show me a small sample? Or maybe a link?

Comment: Rough example added.  You may need to experiment a bit to get the exact effect you want, but hopefully this will get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks I replaced ListBox with ListView but it says before compiling "the type Setter does not support direct content".

Comment: It outlines everything from ControlTemplate.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the Setter.Value element.  Updated.